# Cancellation token for observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How can I cancel the following type of Rx Observable, if the following observable is being created on a StartButton click, i.e from a stop button.

```
var instance = ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance; 

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), instance)
                     .Subscribe(_ =>
                     {
                     Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now); // dummy event
                     }
                     );
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use one of the overloads of `Subscribe` that takes a `CancellationToken`:

```
observable.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow), cancellationToken);
```

This simplifies Jon Skeet's example:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance;
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), instance)
            .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow), cts.Token);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, hadn't seen that. (Both work, of course... I suspect that the Subscribe overloads just call register in the same way :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, all the CancellationToken extension methods do is register Dispose like you did.

Answer (score 14):

You retain the `IDisposable` that was returned by `Subscribe`, and call `Dispose` on it.

There may well be a way of integrating the Rx `IDisposable`-based unsubscription with `CancellationToken` out of the box, but just calling `Dispose` would be a start. (You could always just register a continuation with the cancellation token to call dispose...)

Here's a short but complete example to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance;
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        var disposable = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), instance)
            .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow));
        cts.Token.Register(() => disposable.Dispose());
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bingo! we have a winner, exactly what I was after, cheers @Jon

Comment: I like that you surreptitiously replaced DateTime.Now with DateTime.UtcNow :)

Comment: As I look at a similar question myself, I'm puzzled why Microsoft did not simply make OnNext have a return type of bool. That could then simply mean continue or not. Then the handling code could (as it sees fit) just return false when it's done.